# OpenCV 3.0 and c++ (windows)

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm developing with OpenCV 2.4.11 for C++ and Microsoft Visual Studio. Does somebody know how good the 3.0 Beta for Windows and C++ works? What are the advantages of 3.0 and what are the disadvantages (as it is the beta version, I guess that there are still some bugs)? When is the official "not-beta-version" released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My project shifted to Opencv 3.0 beta version last month,as per official website there are some performance improvement in basic API's.After 1 month of testing here are my observation

1. Syntax of the API's are almost same.
2. No major blocker found so far.
3. Improvement in performance.
4. Increase in the size of DLL's.

But again I must remind you that I have not tried all the api's but so far it good.

Note: As per official website Opencv 3.0 release date was Dec 2014 but still they have not released it.